# CCCrypt padding option doesn't seem to affect decryption

Tags: ios, encryption, commoncrypto

I have a string that has been encrypted using Java

```
Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES/CBC/PKCS5Padding");
cipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, key);
return cipher.doFinal(text.getBytes());
```

(Note that in Java, PKCS5Padding is actually PKCS7Padding when using AES [link](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/9043/what-is-the-difference-between-pkcs5-padding-and-pkcs7-padding/9044#9044))

And my decryption internal code is:

```
CCCryptorStatus cryptStatus = CCCrypt(kCCDecrypt,
                                      kCCAlgorithmAES128,
                                      0,
                                      key.bytes,
                                      kCCBlockSizeAES128,
                                      iv.bytes,
                                      [encrypted bytes],
                                      dataLength,
                                      buffer,
                                      bufferSize,
                                      &numBytesEncrypted);
```

called like:

```
let decryptedData = decryptor.AES128DecryptWithKeyString(key, encryptedString: encodedString) //this does the CCCrypt stuff
let string:NSString = NSString(data: decryptedData, encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding) ?? ""
let data = NSData(base64EncodedString: string as String, options: NSDataBase64DecodingOptions.IgnoreUnknownCharacters)
```

So even though it was encrypted using PKCS5Padding, my decryption works fine despite not giving a padding option. Additionally, if I change the `0` option to `kCCOptionPKCS7Padding` it also works to decrypt.

Is this the expected behavior? Is the padding option only relevant for kCCEncrypt and not kCCDecrypt?

Additionally, if we change the Java encryption to

```
Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES/CBC/NoPadding");
```

and pad the payload manually with zero bytes, then it still decrypts properly regardless of whether I use `0` as an option or `kCCOptionPKCS7Padding`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you say that the padding does not affect decryption are you looking at the output in a hex dump?

The padding will be trailing characters in the range of `0x01` to `0x10` which are non printing ASCII characters so it may seem the same when printing a string that has been encrypted with PKCS#7 padding but decrypted with a padding option.

Add sample output both ways as a hex dump to the question and you should see what is really happening.

The return status does not indicate correct decryption or invalid padding, only gross calling errors.

Example:

```
let keyData     = Array("12345678901234567890123456789012".utf8)
let messageData = Array("Don´t try".utf8)

let encrypted = testCrypt(data:messageData, keyData:keyData, operation:kCCEncrypt, options:UInt32(kCCOptionPKCS7Padding))!
print("encrypted:       \(encrypted)")

let decryptedPKCS7 = testCrypt(data:encrypted, keyData:keyData, operation:kCCDecrypt, options:UInt32(kCCOptionPKCS7Padding))!
print("decrypted PKCS7: \(decryptedPKCS7)")

let decryptedNone = testCrypt(data:encrypted, keyData:keyData, operation:kCCDecrypt, options:UInt32(0))!
print("decrypted None:  \(decryptedNone)")
```

> Output:

```
encrypted:       [136, 95, 194,  76, 137, 107, 196,  39, 245, 108, 106, 84, 139, 49, 14, 139]  
decrypted PKCS7: [68, 111, 110, 194, 180, 116,  32, 116, 114, 121]  
decrypted None:  [68, 111, 110, 194, 180, 116,  32, 116, 114, 121,   6,  6,   6,  6,  6,   6]
```

The trailling six `0x06` bytes are the unremoved padding.

Comment: I'm looking at the NSData and also turning that into a UIImage, and it is properly displaying.

Comment: I see on the NSData the extra padded bytes when I don't specify kCCOptionPKCS7Padding, but I'm confused as to why, when turning it back into base64 encoded data for the UIImage `let data = NSData(base64EncodedString: string as String, options: NSDataBase64DecodingOptions.IgnoreUnknownCharacters)`
the padding bytes disappear. (They disappear even without the IgnoreUnknownCharacters option too)

Comment: Since the data is invalid (contains padding characters) the operation is undefined.